# The lines of force of a point charge near Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: tensor-calculus, general-relativity

I am studying the article written by Hanni and ruffini. I am not so good in the field of general relativity. They have defined the components of Lorentz force in case of Schwarzschild metric as
$$L_{\hat{r}}=\sqrt{g^{rr}} F_{rt} U^{t}=\bigg(1-\frac{2M}{r}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} A_{t},_{r} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{r}}}=A_{t, r}$$ and 
$$L_{\hat{\theta}}=\sqrt{g^{\theta \theta}} F_{\theta t} U^{t}=r A_{t},_{\theta} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{r}}}=(r^2-2Mr)^{-\frac{1}{2}} A_{t},_{\theta}$$
I know that they are considering the charge particle at rest in background of Schwarzschild black hole therefore the only components of electromagnetic potential are
$$F_{rt}     = A_{t},_{r}$$
$$F_{\theta t}=A_{t},_{\theta}.$$
Since there is no magnetic potential induce and $$A_{r}=A_{\theta}=A_{\phi}=0$$
Also they are considering inertial observer with four velocity
$$u^{\alpha}=\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{r}}},0,0,0\bigg)$$
Now I am coming to the point what I want to ask 
May be my question is so simple but I am not finding after searching it on internet, How they define in tensor notation the component of Lorentz force in form
$$L_{\hat{r}}=\sqrt{g^{rr}} F_{rt} U^{t}$$ and $$L_{\hat{\theta}}=\sqrt{g^{\theta \theta}} F_{\theta t} U^{t}$$
Is there any general formula to write these form valid in all spacetime?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems to be a question for Physics SE.